# How to display suggestion view in my app specific keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, autosuggest, custom-keyboard

I have implemented [this](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm). I want to add suggestions, similar to what other keyboards provide however I can't find a solution on how to implement it. My keyboard is application specific so my custom keyboard class does not extend the InputServiceMethod so I'd appreciate some guidance on how to implement this without the InputServiceMethod.

My CustomKeyboard.java class is as follows.

**CustomKeyBoard.java**

```
package com.example.wpa2.applicationspecifickeyboard;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.CompletionInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.view.textservice.SentenceSuggestionsInfo;
import android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession;
import android.view.textservice.SuggestionsInfo;
import android.view.textservice.TextInfo;
import android.view.textservice.TextServicesManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomKeyBoard {

   String translateWord = "";
   Editable edit;
  /**
   * A link to the KeyboardView that is used to render this CustomKeyboard.
   */
private KeyboardView mKeyboardView;
private LatinKeyboardView mInputView;
private CandidateView mCandidateView;
private LatinKeyboard mSymbolsKeyboard;
private LatinKeyboard mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard;
private LatinKeyboard mQwertyKeyboard;
private boolean mCompletionOn;
private boolean mPredictionOn;
private CompletionInfo[] mCompletions;
/**
 * A link to the activity that hosts the {@link #mKeyboardView}.
 */
private Activity mHostActivity;
private InputMethodManager inputMethodManager;
private InputConnection ic;
private StringBuilder mComposing = new StringBuilder();
private String mWordSeparators;
private boolean mCapsLock;
private long mLastShiftTime;
private long mMetaState;
//private SpellCheckerSession mScs;
private List<String> mSuggestions;
  /**
 * The key (code) handler.
 */
private KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener mOnKeyboardActionListener = new KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener() {

    public final static int CodeDelete = -5; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE
    public final static int CodeCancel = -3; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_CANCEL
    public final static int CodePrev = 55000;
    public final static int CodeAllLeft = 55001;
    public final static int CodeLeft = 55002;
    public final static int CodeRight = 55003;
    public final static int CodeAllRight = 55004;
    public final static int CodeNext = 55005;
    public final static int CodeClear = 55006;

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        // NOTE We can say '<Key android:codes="49,50" ... >' in the xml file; all codes come in keyCodes, the first in this list in primaryCode
        // Get the EditText and its Editable

        View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
        //if (focusCurrent == null || focusCurrent.getClass() != EditText.class) return;
        if (focusCurrent == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            EditText edittext = (EditText) focusCurrent;
            Editable editable = edittext.getText();
            int start = edittext.getSelectionStart();

            edit = editable;
            // Apply the key to the edittext
            if (primaryCode == CodeCancel) {
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeDelete) {
                if (editable != null && start > 0) editable.delete(start - 1, start);
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeClear) {
                if (editable != null) editable.clear();
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeLeft) {
                if (start > 0) edittext.setSelection(start - 1);
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeRight) {
                if (start < edittext.length()) edittext.setSelection(start + 1);
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeAllLeft) {
                edittext.setSelection(0);
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeAllRight) {
                edittext.setSelection(edittext.length());
            } else if (primaryCode == CodePrev) {
                View focusNew = edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_BACKWARD);
                if (focusNew != null) focusNew.requestFocus();
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeNext) {
                View focusNew = edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_FORWARD);
                if (focusNew != null) focusNew.requestFocus();
            } else if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE && mInputView != null) {
                Keyboard current = mInputView.getKeyboard();
                if (current == mSymbolsKeyboard || current == mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard) {
                    setLatinKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
                } else {
                    setLatinKeyboard(mSymbolsKeyboard);
                    mSymbolsKeyboard.setShifted(false);
                }
            } else if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT) {
                handleShift();
            } else { // insert character
                editable.insert(start, Character.toString((char) primaryCode));
                mComposing.append((char) primaryCode);
            }
        }

        Log.d("Test", "KEYCODE: " + primaryCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
   //inputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(
  //String.valueOf((char) primaryCode), 1);
  //InputConnection ic = inputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection();
  //if (ic == null) {
      //return;
  //}
 //ic.beginBatchEdit();
        if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
          //commitTyped(ic);
            commitTyped();
        }
      //ic.endBatchEdit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    //InputConnection ic = inputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection();
    //if (ic == null) {
      // return;
     //}
   //ic.beginBatchEdit();
        if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
           //commitTyped(ic);
            commitTyped();
        }
   //ic.commitText(text, 0);
   //ic.endBatchEdit();
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
    }
};

/**
 * Create a custom keyboard, that uses the KeyboardView (with resource id <var>viewid</var>) of the <var>host</var> activity,
 * and load the keyboard layout from xml file <var>layoutid</var> (see {@link Keyboard} for description).
 * Note that the <var>host</var> activity must have a <var>KeyboardView</var> in its layout (typically aligned with the bottom of the activity).
 * Note that the keyboard layout xml file may include key codes for navigation; see the constants in this class for their values.
 * Note that to enable EditText's to use this custom keyboard, call the {@link #registerEditText(int)}.
 *
 * @param host     The hosting activity.
 * @param viewid   The id of the KeyboardView.
 * @param layoutid The id of the xml file containing the keyboard layout.
 */
public CustomKeyBoard(Activity host, int viewid, int layoutid) {
    mHostActivity = host;

    mInputView = (LatinKeyboardView) mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid);
    mInputView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));
   //  mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview balloons
    mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);

    mWordSeparators = host.getResources().getString(R.string.word_separators);

    // Hide the standard keyboard initially
  mHostActivity.getWindow().
setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    //to set other keyboard layout.
    mQwertyKeyboard = new LatinKeyboard(mHostActivity, R.xml.qwerty);
    mSymbolsKeyboard = new LatinKeyboard(mHostActivity, R.xml.symbols);
    mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard = new LatinKeyboard(mHostActivity, R.xml.symbols_shift);

    mPredictionOn = true;
    mCompletionOn = false;
    mCompletions = null;
    //final TextServicesManager tsm = (TextServicesManager) mHostActivity.getSystemService(
            Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE);
   // mScs = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, null, this, true);
  //ic=mInputView.onCreateInputConnection();
}


/**
 * Returns whether the CustomKeyboard is visible.
 */
public boolean isCustomKeyboardVisible() {
    return mInputView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}

/**
 * Make the CustomKeyboard visible, and hide the system keyboard for view v.
 */
public void showCustomKeyboard(View v) {
    mInputView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mInputView.setEnabled(true);
    if (v != null)
      //v.requestFocus();
      //((InputMethodManager) mHostActivity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        ((InputMethodManager) mHostActivity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}

/**
 * Make the CustomKeyboard invisible.
 */
public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
    mInputView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mInputView.setEnabled(false);
}

/**
 * Register <var>EditText<var> with resource id <var>resid</var> (on the hosting activity) for using this custom keyboard.
 *
 * @param resid The resource id of the EditText that registers to the custom keyboard.
 */
public void registerEditText(int resid) {
    // Find the EditText 'resid'
    final EditText edittext = (EditText) mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);
    // Make the custom keyboard appear
    edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        // NOTE By setting the on focus listener, we can show the custom keyboard when the edit box gets focus, but also hide it when the edit box loses focus
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) showCustomKeyboard(v);
            else hideCustomKeyboard();
        }
    });
    edittext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // NOTE By setting the on click listener, we can show the custom keyboard again, by tapping on an edit box that already had focus (but that had the keyboard hidden).
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCustomKeyboard(v);
        }
    });

    // Disable standard keyboard hard way
    // NOTE There is also an easy way: 'edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)' (but you will not have a cursor, and no 'edittext.setCursorVisible(true)' doesn't work )
    edittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            EditText edittext = (EditText) v;
            int inType = edittext.getInputType();       // Backup the input type
            edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard keyboard
            edittext.onTouchEvent(event);               // Call native handler
            edittext.setInputType(inType);              // Restore input type
         //edittext.setCursorVisible(true);
        //edittext.requestFocus();
            return true; // Consume touch event
        }
    });

    onCreateCandidatesView();
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            updateCandidates();

        }
    });


    // Disable spell check (hex strings look like words to Android)
    //edittext.setInputType(edittext.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
}

/**
 * Helper function to commit any text being composed in to the editor.
 */

private void commitTyped() {
    if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
   //mInputView.onCreateInputConnection().commitText(mComposing, mComposing.length());
        edit.append(mComposing);
        mComposing.setLength(0);
        updateCandidates();
    }
}


/**
 * Helper to send a key down / key up pair to the current editor.
 */
private void keyDownUp(int keyEventCode) {
    inputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
            new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyEventCode));
    inputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
            new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyEventCode));
}


/**
 * Helper to send a character to the editor as raw key events.
 */
private void sendKey(int keyCode) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case '\n':
            keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
            break;
        default:
            if (keyCode >= '0' && keyCode <= '9') {
                keyDownUp(keyCode - '0' + KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0);
            } else {
                inputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(String.valueOf((char) keyCode), 1);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private String getWordSeparators() {
    return mWordSeparators;
}

public boolean isWordSeparator(int code) {
    String separators = getWordSeparators();
    return separators.contains(String.valueOf((char) code));
}

// this method not used currently anywhere.
private void handleBackspace() {
    final int length = mComposing.length();
    if (length > 1) {
        mComposing.delete(length - 1, length);
        inputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(mComposing, 1);
        updateCandidates();
    } else if (length > 0) {
        mComposing.setLength(0);
        inputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection().commitText("", 0);
        updateCandidates();
    } else {
        keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL);
    }
    updateShiftKeyState(inputMethodService.getCurrentInputEditorInfo());

}

/**
 * Update the list of available candidates from the current composing
 * text.  This will need to be filled in by however you are determining
 * candidates.
 */
private void updateCandidates() {
    if (!mCompletionOn) {
        if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            //list.add(mComposing.toString());
            Log.d("SoftKeyboard", "REQUESTING: " + mComposing.toString());
            //mScs.getSentenceSuggestions(new TextInfo[]{new TextInfo(mComposing.toString())}, 5);
            setSuggestions(list, true, true);
        } else {
            setSuggestions(null, false, false);
        }
    }
}

public void setSuggestions(List<String> suggestions, boolean completions,
                           boolean typedWordValid) {
    if (suggestions != null && suggestions.size() > 0) {
     // this method's alternative should be used by me if available. means to show suggestion view . 
    //inputMethodService.setCandidatesViewShown(true);
        mInputView.setVerticalCorrection(1);
    } else if (inputMethodService.isExtractViewShown()) {
    //inputMethodService.setCandidatesViewShown(true);
    }
    mSuggestions = suggestions;
    if (mCandidateView != null) {
        mCandidateView.setSuggestions(suggestions, completions, typedWordValid);
    }
}

private void handleShift() {
    if (mInputView == null) {
        return;
    }

    Keyboard currentKeyboard = mInputView.getKeyboard();
    if (mQwertyKeyboard == currentKeyboard) {
        // Alphabet keyboard
        checkToggleCapsLock();
        mInputView.setShifted(mCapsLock || !mInputView.isShifted());
    } else if (currentKeyboard == mSymbolsKeyboard) {
        mSymbolsKeyboard.setShifted(true);
        setLatinKeyboard(mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard);
        mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard.setShifted(true);
    } else if (currentKeyboard == mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard) {
        mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard.setShifted(false);
        setLatinKeyboard(mSymbolsKeyboard);
        mSymbolsKeyboard.setShifted(false);
    }
}

private void checkToggleCapsLock() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (mLastShiftTime + 800 > now) {
        mCapsLock = !mCapsLock;
        mLastShiftTime = 0;
    } else {
        mLastShiftTime = now;
    }
}

/**
 * Helper to update the shift state of our keyboard based on the initial
 * editor state.
 */
private void updateShiftKeyState(EditorInfo attr) {
    if (attr != null && mInputView != null && mQwertyKeyboard == mInputView.getKeyboard()) {
        int caps = 0;

    //EditorInfo ei = inputMethodService.getCurrentInputEditorInfo()
    //if (ei != null && ei.inputType != InputType.TYPE_NULL) {
   //caps= inputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection().getCursorCapsMode(attr.inputType);
   //}

     mInputView.setShifted(mCapsLock || caps != 0);
    }
}

private void handleCharacter(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    if (inputMethodService.isInputViewShown()) {
        if (mInputView.isShifted()) {
            primaryCode = Character.toUpperCase(primaryCode);
        }
    }
    if (mPredictionOn) {
        mComposing.append((char) primaryCode);
        inputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(mComposing, 1);
        updateShiftKeyState(inputMethodService.getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
        updateCandidates();
    } else {
        inputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(
                String.valueOf((char) primaryCode), 1);
    }
}

private void setLatinKeyboard(LatinKeyboard nextKeyboard) {
    mInputView.setKeyboard(nextKeyboard);
}

public void pickSuggestionManually(int index) {
    if (mCompletionOn && mCompletions != null && index >= 0
            && index < mCompletions.length) {
        CompletionInfo ci = mCompletions[index];
        mSuggestions.add(ci.toString());
      //getCurrentInputConnection().commitCompletion(ci);
        if (mCandidateView != null) {
            mCandidateView.clear();
        }
   //updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
    } else if (mComposing.length() > 0) {

        if (mPredictionOn && mSuggestions != null && index >= 0) {
            mComposing.replace(0, mComposing.length(), mSuggestions.get(index));
        }
        commitTyped();

    }
}

public View onCreateCandidatesView() {
    mCandidateView = new CandidateView(mHostActivity);
    mCandidateView.setService(this);
    return mCandidateView;
    }

 }
```